# Can you use virsh to reset vm id sequence?

Tags: virtual-machines, libvirt, qemu, virsh

Question in regards to "**Id**" for running VMs, using virsh running local Qemu VMs.

command `virsh list` will bring up a list of the current running VMs defined, eg,

 **Id** Name State

 -------------------

 **1** ubuntu running

upon stopping and undefining the current VM (ubuntu)

the next newly defined VM (domain) will have the "**Id**" of **2** instead given the "**Id**" of **1**


Is there a way to reset this Id? or further manage this assignment? Can't seem to find more documentation on this topic when browsing the libvirt documentation.

Comment: For what purpose you need that? What is your real problem which you want to solve this way? This ID is [runtime information](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/ru-ru/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/virtualization_deployment_and_administration_guide/sect-managing_guest_virtual_machines_with_virsh-retrieving_guest_virtual_machine_information); it has no meaning for stopped VMs.

Comment: Thanks @NikitaKipriyanov, yup I've came across the second page through one of my searches, now skimming through the first reference you provided + running VMs + rebooting my host machine, now I see that the "Id" is a runtime reference of the running VM number for the current Libvirt session. eg, if you stop and start a VM it increases for the newly started job (VM), if you reboot your machine it restarts from Id #1 for the first VM that the host machine started.